# Is my apt-get dependency tree corrupted?

Tags: apt, dependencies, dpkg

I wanted to uninstall the `libboost` libraries. I wrote in the console:

```
sudo apt-get remove libboost-*
```

But looking more precisely at the console output, I noticed `apt-get` was ready to remove several packages that looks *completely* unrelated to `libboost`

Although I may not use once in a month `compiz`, `ubuntu-desktop`, or `unity`, I don't want them to be removed. And I can't understand they are programmed for removal ?

So I am wondering if there could be a mess in the dependence tree, and if there were any operation to put the situation back to normal ?

More precisely the end of the console output is:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libtorque2 texlive-fonts-recommended libopenmpi1.3 libibverbs-dev tipa mpi-default-dev lyx-common libnuma1 gccxml texlive-fonts-recommended-doc libibve
  libicu-dev gwibber libopenmpi-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  akonadi-server aptitude compiz compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-fusion-plugins-main compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-extra compiz-plugins-main compiz-pl
  kdepim-runtime libboost-all-dev libboost-date-time-dev libboost-date-time1.46-dev libboost-date-time1.46.1 libboost-dbg libboost-dev libboost-doc libbo
  libboost-filesystem1.46-dev libboost-filesystem1.46.1 libboost-graph-dev libboost-graph-parallel-dev libboost-graph-parallel1.46-dev libboost-graph-par
  libboost-graph1.46-dev libboost-graph1.46.1 libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-iostreams1.46-dev libboost-iostreams1.46.1 libboost-math-dev libboost-math1
  libboost-mpi-dev libboost-mpi-python-dev libboost-mpi1.46-dev libboost-mpi1.46.1 libboost-program-options-dev libboost-program-options1.46-dev libboost
  libboost-python-dev libboost-python1.46-dev libboost-python1.46.1 libboost-regex-dev libboost-regex1.40.0 libboost-regex1.46-dev libboost-regex1.46.1 l
  libboost-serialization1.46-dev libboost-serialization1.46.1 libboost-signals-dev libboost-signals1.46-dev libboost-signals1.46.1 libboost-system-dev li
  libboost-system1.46.1 libboost-test-dev libboost-test1.46-dev libboost-test1.46.1 libboost-thread-dev libboost-thread1.46-dev libboost-thread1.46.1 lib
  libboost-wave1.46-dev libboost-wave1.46.1 libboost1.46-dbg libboost1.46-dev libboost1.46-doc libtorrent-rasterbar6 lyx python-kde4 qbittorrent software
  tasksel-data ubuntu-desktop uex unity
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 77 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
After this operation, 489 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency tree is **NOT corrupted**.

using `apt-rpdepends` and the command line I got:

```
$ sudo apt-rdepends unity | grep boost
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Depends: libboost-serialization1.46.1 (>= 1.46.1-1)
libboost-serialization1.46.1
```

So indeed, all those executables *are using libboost*, with various version numbers, and the biggest conclusion is that I must not uninstall libboost...